# wordpress blog page geting custom field of first post

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields, posts

i am facing a bad problem. it will be well appreciated if any one can help me regarding my problem.

i am using custom fields on posts and pages, just like removing Page navigation, Footer, Sidebar, ETC. when i use custom field on my recently added post (first post on displaying on Blog page) for example i remove navigation from that recently added post it also remove the navigation from Blog page where all the post are listing.

i am removing all the element from Jquery .remove() and i add all this code in footer

how to handle this i do not want any change on blog page if i am making any change in recently added post from custom fields.

```
<?php
   global $post;
   if(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_remove_topnavigation', true)=='yes'): ?>

   jQuery('#branding #navigation').remove();

<?php else : ?>

 //Do nothing

<?php  endif; ?>
```

Comment: `get_post_meta` function returns `true` or `false` and not `yes`. So you condition is totally incorrect. Also jQuery code should be in `<script>` tag.

Comment: @Rikesh `get_post_meta()` will return the first key as string if 3rd parameter is set to true..

Comment: i have also test this by installing new wordpress and create a new blog page and assign that page as a post page from setting and again tried to add custom field in "hello world" post still that problem is there. I have tried this simple Custom field Code i think you guys should try that. This is first time i am facing this type of problem. <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'testing', true); ?>

Answer (score 0):

You should post the code of the page , or at least a link, because your problem is not in the use of the `custom fields` but in the selectors you are using .

instead of using `#branding #navigation` , which are maybe (probably) shared by your other navigation (although they are IDs, but bad theme coders are not rare in this world ) .

So the solution would be either to isolate & identify better the selectors, or add another selector (class) to the recently added post.

If you had included the page source code , it would have been much easier ..

Comment: Now when i am adding The code in header.php to remove navigation Like this:
    <?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_mer_topnav', true) ): ?>
     <!-- Nothing -->
   <?php else : ?>
    <div id="navigation">
      <nav id="access" role="navigation">
       <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
      </nav>
                 </div>
   <?php  endif; ?>  

i am still facing this problem

Comment: Let me tel you what i have done.

i have created a blog page from pages tab. then from Setting > Reading i assign Blog page as a post page. Now all my post are on my Blog page.

now when ever i use custom fields in Recently added Post(Last Post) that custom field also effect on Blog page. where all the posts are listed.

Comment: Please Help me if i am doing anything Wrong

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to mix server-side and client-side code incorrectly. What your server-side PHP code needs to do is put some "marker" (probably a class attribute) on anything that your JavaScript code (via JQuery) needs to remove. Then your JavaScript code needs to look for that marker and then remove it.

So the body of your `if` statement needs to set a class attribute (let's call it "`nobrandnav`") on whatever HTML block (probably a `div`) is being output. Your JavaScript code needs to start off like:

```
jquery(".nobrandnav").
  find(whatever navigation is needed to find your branding).
  remove();
```